# Hidden Features of `screen`

Tags: gnu-screen

Since I use the [*nix command `screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) all day, and I couldn't find anyone starting this question, I figured it should be started. You know the drill: community wiki, one answer per features so we all can vote.

Comment: screen is so useful it belongs on all the sites:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614/gnu-screen-survival-guide

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I *love* using it for connecting to serial consoles, i.e.

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 19200
```

This command simply opens up a connection to serial port 0 (ttyS0) with a baud speed of 19200

Comment: this is one of my favorite things to freak people out with, truly one of screen's least expected features

Comment: And truly one of my favorites.  No need to deal with, or configure, minicom, conserver, etc.  I felt like a little kid in a candy store when I discovered this.

Comment: Absolutely - it's nice to have a screen session open, split into two windows, with both USB-Serial dongles visible.

Answer (score 10):

The best feature of `screen` is Byobu (formerly screen-profiles) which comes with Ubuntu by default since Jaunty: https://launchpad.net/byobu

It's a configuration manager with very nice defaults, tons of status notifications and useful keyboard shortcuts (i.e. f2 for new screen, f3-f4 for prev/next etc.)

I really don't go anywhere without it anymore :)

Answer (score 10):

From KTamas's amswer: More than one person can use the same screen, i.e. if a friend of yours `ssh` into your computer, then he can connect to your screen. It's great when two or three people are working on the same projects.

Comment: This is much better for following what remote support users are doing, and killing their session if they're upto no good!

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly a "hidden feature"; but a properly setup .screenrc file can make a world of difference.  One of the better examples out there can be found by googling screenrc and 'brad sims' - he has an excellent file to tinker with.

that said, my favourite setting would be bindkey:

```
# bind F7  to detach screen session from this terminal
# bind F8  to kill current screen window.
# bind F9  to create a new screen
# bind F10 to rename current screen window
# bind F11 to move to previous window
# bind F12 to move to next window
bindkey -k k7 detach
bindkey -k k8 kill
bindkey -k k9 screen
bindkey -k k; title
bindkey -k F1 prev
bindkey -k F2 next
```

Comment: Considering that ctrl+a is used too often outside of screen (beginning of line in bash anyone?) I like this.

Comment: ctrl+a/ctrl+e for moving the cursor, but also when minicom is running in a screen. Ctrl+a,a,o for options...

Answer (score 6):

I can't remember who I stole this from (someone on dotfile.org). I've modified it slightly for ssh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# scr - Runs a command in a fresh screen
#
# Get the current directory and the name of command

wd=`pwd`
cmd=$1
shift

# We can tell if we are running inside screen by looking
# for the STY environment variable.  If it is not set we
# only need to run the command, but if it is set then
# we need to use screen.

if [ -z "$STY" ]; then
        $cmd $*
else
        # Screen needs to change directory so that
        # relative file names are resolved correctly.
        screen -X chdir $wd

        # Ask screen to run the command
        if [ $cmd == "ssh" ]; then
                screen -X screen -t ""${1##*@}"" $cmd $*
        else
                screen -X screen -t "$cmd $*" $cmd $*
        fi
fi
```

Then I set the following bash aliases:

```
vim() {
        scr vim $*
}

man() {
        scr man $*
}

info() {
        scr info $*
}

watch() {
        scr watch $*
}

ssh() {
        scr ssh $*
}
```

It opens a new screen for the above aliases and iff using ssh, it renames the screen title with the ssh hostname.

Cheers z0mbix

Comment: :o. Did you lift and adapt it from me? https://gist.github.com/137214

Comment: No, I think it was from a last.fm staff member who blogger about it once.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I find useful is that screen can emulate a larger width than your terminal. I find this useful if I'm using `less` to real log files, and I don't want the lines to wrap. Using:

<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`width -w 999`

I can set `screen`'s with to be wider than my terminal, and log lines in `less` won't wrap.

Comment: FYI, the less option `-s` will tell it not to wrap lines. You can use `Left` and `Right` to scroll the lines.

Answer (score 4):

The ability to change the control key with -ethat when starting screen.  I use it so I can nest screen sessions inside each other.  Example: "screen -e ^w^x" makes the control key ctr-w.

Answer (score 2):

One nice feature: you can use `backtick` to pull in extra info for display in a caption.  For example, I have a script that output a one-line summary of new mail counts in various folders, and I have that appear in the bottom line if my screen session along with the hostname with a config that looks like this:

```
backtick 1 15 15 /home/waltermundt/bin/newmail

caption always
caption string "%{.kW}%1` example.com %{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %{.gW}%h%{-}"
```

The key is the %1` bit, which refers to the output of backtick job 1.

(I use `hardstatus` as the xterm title string and have it set differently, thus the use of `caption` instead of `hardstatus alwayslastline`.)

Answer (score 2):

Not a "hidden" feature, but the ability to share a screen session with another active user is very useful.

There are complicated ways to set up screen sharing, including access control permissions and user name management.  What I most often do with coworkers is much more quick & dirty:

1. Log into machine in question in new window.
2. Allow anyone to write to my terminal:  `chmod 777 $(tty)`
3. Sudo to their account:  `sudo su <username>`
4. Share their screen:  `screen -x <session>`

This doesn't require any advance configuration or password sharing.

Answer (score 1):

A little cheat sheet I have printed out for myself;

(Note: Everything is preceeded by <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>)

```
A: rename a window   
": show a list of windows   
d: detatch session
```

And `screen -D -R` to deattach and reattach a running session (in case you somehow lose access to your session).

None of these are really hidden features, but these are the features I find to be the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's a core feature, but of course the best is <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to talk directly to screen.  `: screen -t title ssh hostname` etc.