# SCREEN setup tips

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

How do you use the "screen" tool ?

I'm looking for best practices and config tips :

- To keep clean and ordered sessions on several servers
- To have a beautiful colored interface
- To have a fully featured taskbar
- To get many other features I didn't think about

I'm currently using screen only to run commands and be able to "detach" the terminal and logout. What do you use it for ? What are the other use cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still recommend the [Gentoo wiki article for screen](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Screen) tips (even though some of it was lost).

I highly recommend you replace Ctrl-A with backtick (``` escape `` ```
 in the screenrc) because it makes for more comfortable screen use. The above link tells how to do that, how to make a fancy taskbar (hard status string), and more.

Plug alert, I blogged about some screen tips [here](http://www.kbrandt.com/2009/04/my-not-so-shabby-screen-and-gnome-terminal-setup.html) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good post on some lesser known/hidden screen features:

[Hidden Features of `screen`](https://serverfault.com/questions/81544/hidden-features-of-screen)